# Google Calendar Oauth2 API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm currently trying to integrate Google Calendar with my application. Using this https://github.com/northworld/google_calendar

I've followed the steps of creating Oauth client ID and so on. But now questioning how to save authorisation code returned from callback which is something like `Oauth2Callback?code=aaabbbbccc1234`

Would I have to rely on user session cookies to identify user and save the code into DB or is there some other better ways of doing this?

What is the standard way to deal with the integration?

Answer (score 0):

For this task You can use [zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2 gem](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2).

In readme.md of this gem, You can read full solutions for this.

For Your question, OAUTH2 have two steps.
In first step, You receive 'oauth code'. But it is only temporary.
After this, in second step, You send 'oauth code' and receive 'oauth token'. This token You should use in Google API.

So, as an additional advise, You should create google applications and enable Google Calendar API for Your Applications...

Comment: Thanks. But I'm dealing with single page application here. How do I do this with omniauth-google-oauth2 gem?

Comment: Also I already have email authentication and I just want to use Google Calendar integration. It sounds like I need to authenticate user twice which I don't want

Comment: In my projects I use separately 'standart' and 'omniauth' authentications too. About this is good advice in article http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/